# Distinct not working (ASP Awesome control)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I am sending an ASP Awesome Combobox entries for a dropdown using JSON.

Code below:

```
 public ActionResult GetEngineerData()
    {
        var items = db.Results.Where(x=>x.Engineer != null).Select(o=>new KeyContent(o.Engineer,o.Engineer)).Distinct()
                    

        return Json(items);
    }
```

This does not provide a distinct list, instead there are many duplicates.
I have also tried doing this (positioning distinct before the Select KeyContent code):

```
public ActionResult GetEngineerData()
        {
            var items = db.Results.Where(x=>x.Engineer != null).Distinct().Select(o=>new KeyContent(o.Engineer,o.Engineer))
                    

        return Json(items);
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is pulling from a table of around 100 items for the "Engineer" column. There are only around 4 unique items in this list, but on run time the dropdown populates with all entries in the table from the column "Engineer"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when creating a `new KeyContent`, you get *distinct* instances - different objects, even if their values are the same.
that's why your first code doesn't work.

in your second one, you check if the `Results` are distinct, and for each distinct one, you select the `Engineer`.

If you want distinct engineers, try this:

```cs
     public ActionResult GetEngineerData()
     {
        var items = db.Results
            .Where(x=>x.Engineer != null)   //eliminate empty values
            .Select(x=>x.Engineer)          //select only the engineer-item
            .Distinct()                     //remove _duplicate engineers_ from the list
            .Select(x=>new KeyContent(x,x));//for each unique engineer, create a KeyContent instance
                    

        return Json(items);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but it still doesn't work. I get the following error now "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities"

Comment: curious that didn't happen in your original code. try adding a `.AsEnumerable()` after `.Distinct()`

Comment: I added a ToList() after the Select(x=>x.Engineer) to circumvent the LINQ to entities issue and it fixed it. Thanks for your help!